# JQuery not initializing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a basic Jquery script to hide a button after it is clicked on an HTML Page. However, when it is clicked the button does nothing. code is below. JQuery has been update to it's most recent version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function(){
   $('#button').click(function(){
      $('#button').toggle();
   });  
});

</script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id = "button">Find Printer</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Are you positive that jquery is loading... check fiddler, debuggers...

Comment: works for me => http://jsfiddle.net/39E9p/

Comment: Why use `.toggle()`?  After you hide it, you won't be able to click it again!  Just use `.hide()`.

Comment: @DerekHenderson - agreed, plus the use of `$(this)` over querying the same selector, plus the use of the shorthand for `$(document).ready` ... a lot that can be improved here, even with such a small amount of items.

Comment: should the script tag containing the jQuery source come before the document.ready?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to load jquery first before you use `$(document).ready()`. Move the script tag for jQuery above your javascript tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.1.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function(){
   $('#button').click(function(){
      $('#button').toggle();
   });  
});

</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id = "button">Find Printer</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script has loaded before you've loaded jQuery. Move the jQuery link before your code block and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the jQuery script first and then call `$(document).ready()`.